# Bundle Expect with shell script to bypass installation of Expect

Tags: linux, expect

I want to create a shell script that uses the Expect library however Expect is not installed on any of the systems where I want to run the script. I also cannot install the library on these systems either. Can I build Expect from source and then put in same directory as the script? How would you go about this?

Comment: I don't have any experience compiling expect to a static binary executable. What have you tried?

Comment: What do you mean by *"I also cannot install the library on these systems either"*? You don't have root privileges?

Comment: take a look at [sexpect](https://github.com/clarkwang/sexpect). you can write *expect* scripts with shell scripts only. it's easy to build and it's small and it does not depend on 3rd party libs.

Comment: I suggest that you use a Starpack for this purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes you can, and it's not difficult.

1. Download Expect sources from https://sourceforge.net/projects/expect/files/latest/download?source=files
2. Unpack sources

   ```
   gunzip expect.tar.gz
   tar -xvf expect.tar
   ```

This will create a directory containing the Expect distribution. Change to that directory and

3. Configure sources for compilation:

   ```
   ./configure --prefix=~/
   ```

With `--prefix` parameter you specify where Expect should be installed. `~/` in my example is a shortcut for current user home directory, so it will be installed locally for your user only and you don't need root privileges this way to install it. In case you have root privileges and want to install it system-wide, you can omit `--prefix` parameter.

4. Compile Expect:

   ```
   make
   ```
5. And install it:

   ```
   make install
   ```

And that's it :)

Comment: Based on my experience it's not that easy to build Expect from source. It require's Tcl's private header files which may not be installed by default.

Comment: Yes, Expect to compile requires Tcl. Also requires c compiler, make suite etc. But my point stands - it's easy, even if you have to install also some required dependencies. But if you have some specific problem I'm happy to help.